# The difference between modulus and subtracton in php operator

Tags: php, operators

I am learning some php operators especially `%` and `-`

For the subtraction operator of `-` I learned it from this link [subtraction](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_oper_subtraction)

While the modulus operator of `%` I learned it from this link [modulus](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_oper_modulus)

Both in the example use the int of 6 and 10

```
$x = 10;
$y = 6;
```

In modulus there is an example like:

```
  echo $x % $y //will output 4
```

In subtraction there the example:

```
  echo $x - $y //will output 4
```

So the output for these two operators is same each other.

what's the difference between them?

Comment: Try `$x = 20` and notice the difference. This is grade school arithmetic.

Comment: The difference is the same ___in the specific case of $x = 10 and $y = 6__, and that's just coincidence. Now set $x = 24 and $y = 5 and see if they're still the same

Comment: You could ask a similar question about `+` and `-` if you set one of the values to `0`. Only because two operators return the same result for a given input doesn't mean there is no difference between them (I assume that's why asked). Also Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because StackOverflow isn't here to replace learning grade school arithmetic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple to understand for anyone who know some arithmetic operations.  The `%` and `-` operators work same way in all programming languages.  When you take two operands - and use the modulus operator, `%` - you will get remainder of the division.  The `-` operator is simply the subtraction operation.  You don't need to be confused when both operators yield same results.  Just a matter of coincidence.

[image: Sweet drawing of long division]

Answer (score 2):

The modulus operator (`%`) divides the two numbers and returns you the remainder (remember your long division).

The fact that both `10 - 6` and `10 % 6` is 4 is a coincidence.

Comment: Not so much a coincidence as the expected behavior when `$x` is between `$y` and `2*$y`.

Comment: @Barmar: Shush.  I swear I remember my grade school math and how  long division works!  :-P

Comment: Does in modulus it means that 10 + 6 = 16 : 4 = 4?

Comment: @alisa: Do you know what "remainder" means?  Do you remember how to do "long division"?

Comment: I am sorry, I still have no idea about this. Can you please tell me how does it work?

Comment: @alisa: You don't know how to do long division?  Did you not learn that in school?  Does this (http://www.mathsisfun.com/long_division2.html) not ring any bells?